# Travis task with "brew test-bot" failing over outdated Command Line Tools

Tags: xcode, homebrew, travis-ci, homebrew-cask

I am updating `travis-ci` tests for homebrew tap and `brew test-bot` is failing with an error:

```
Warning: A newer Command Line Tools release is available.
Update them from Software Update in the App Store.
```

I got the right environment with `softwareupdate`, but wonder if there is way to detour this until the fresh version is not in Travis' VM image?

- yml file:

```
os: osx
language: c
compiler: clang
osx_image: xcode10.1
cache:
  directories:
    - /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/bundle

before_install:
  - softwareupdate --install -a
  - sudo chown -R "$USER" "$(brew --repo)"
  - travis_retry brew update
  - HOMEBREW_TAP_DIR="$(brew --repo "$TRAVIS_REPO_SLUG")"
  - mkdir -p "$HOMEBREW_TAP_DIR"
  - rm -rf "$HOMEBREW_TAP_DIR"
  - ln -s "$PWD" "$HOMEBREW_TAP_DIR"

script:
  - brew test-bot
  - brew cask audit ./Casks/*.rb
  - brew cask install -v ./Casks/*.rb
```

Also noticed that `brew tap-new` template now using Azure pipelines instead of Travis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the long run, it seems that the best solution is to move to Azure pipelines, since that's what the homebrew core team seems to be targeting with the brew test-bot tool.

Meanwhile, your solution is the best available.